# Images not showing up in Flutter App when using rFlutter_alert

Tags: flutter

I am using the rFlutter_alert package, but when I try to add an image, the image does not appear. This is the function I am using:

```
  _onAlertWithCustomImagePressed(context) {
    Alert(
      context: context,
      title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
      desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
      image: Image.asset("assets/success.png"),
    ).show();
  }
```

The image (success.png) is in the assets folder of the project and I added the image to pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/success.png
```

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
The issue has been solved since V2.0.3 according to the [author comment](https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert/issues/108#issuecomment-891924084) in the issue.

---

There is an open issue for this problem which is opened in the GitHub repo, you can check it out via this link [Custom Image doesn't show up #108](https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert/issues/108)